# Trying to Execute a program through a PHP script.

Tags: php, iis

Here is the setup I am running.

Windows 7
IIS 7.5
PHP 5.5.8

All I want to do is execute a program that I have that will run independent of user input, I just need it to run on it's own, it can even run in the background, the GUI is not necessary.

This is the code I have so far.

```
<?php
echo passthru('C:\Users\User1\Documents\StartFolder\testing.exe');
?>
```

When I run the PHP file, it says in my Task Manager that the EXE. is open but it doesn't complete the action (just copying a file from one folder to another) but when I run the EXE. outside of PHP is runs and completes the action just fine.

Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: How about using `exec` command instead [http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php]

Comment: I have tried that as well and receive the same outcome.

Comment: Do you have [safe_mode](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) enabled? UAC enabled? Also see docs for [passthru](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) "If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends."

Comment: @BrockHensley I don't believe I have safe mode enabled or UAC. I tend to believe that the issue may be the output as you have mentioned, but I don't know how to send the output of the program to a file. All the program does is copy a file from one program to another so Im not sure if there would even be any output.

Comment: Can you run the .exe in a cmd window yourself to see what the output is? Even if its saying "Successfully copied" it could be the cause.

Comment: @BrockHensley I just ran it in the cmd window and it didn't show any sort of output. Could it be the way i'm calling the program? Do I need to add some sort of parameter to it?

Comment: Not sure... try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php#50540